# How to implement constraint that a type parameter is a parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameterized-types

I'd like to make a program that from a `FileDialog` takes a `.class` (or maybe a `.java` file) file on the condition that the class is a generic type, such as `LinkedList<T>`, `ArrayList<T>`, or whatever data structure the user selects. I would like to throw an exception if the class is not a generic type. For further explanation, I would like to test if

```
inputClassX instanceof ParameterizedType
```

but because I would like to test any arbitrary class that may not implement `ParameterizedType`, I cannot do that test.

How would I test if an object, or a `Class`, is a generic type?

Comment: I believe that the compiled class holds no information about generic type parameters, so no, you can't do a runtime test for that without looking at the source. What is the purpose of opening a .class file here? Is it for a plug-in system of some sort?

Comment: @E_net4 The class file holds basically all of the information known at compile-time except (off the top of my head) annotations which aren't runtime retention and (depending on compilation options) parameter names of methods. Type arguments to a particular object from a class instance creation expression (like `new ArrayList<String>()`) are what is erased per se.

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary `Class` object, you could check the length of the array returned by `getTypeParameters`, if it's non-zero, it means the class has generic type parameters:

```
System.out.println(String.class.getTypeParameters().length != 0); // false
System.out.println(List.class.getTypeParameters().length != 0); // true
```